# Query for Selecting only Selected Fc's from a GDB

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, enterprise-geodatabase

I need to version n number of fc's which start with sde."ENT-QA". I need to select only those feature classes and run versioning for it. Can anyone help me in writing the query for selecting only fc's which start with sde."ENT-QA". Remeber ENT-QA is mentioned has quotes. Thanks in advance.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace= r"xyz.sde"
fdList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","","")

for fc in fdList:
    print fc
    arcpy.RegisterAsVersioned_management(fc, "NO_EDITS_TO_BASE")
    print "fc registered"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use a wildcard with your ListFeatureClasses statement like:

```
fdList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("\"ENT-QA\"*","","")
```

as shown in [Arc10 ListFeatureClasses online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001n000000)?

**UPDATE:**
code updated based upon nmpeterson's comments.

Comment: If you want to ensure that you're only selecting feature classes whose names contain `"ENT-QA"` and not `ENT-QA` (without the quotation marks), this would be `fdList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("\"ENT-QA\"","","")`

Comment: Nice catch.  I overlooked the part about the value *in quotes*.  Thanks for posting the correct syntax.  I will update my response.

Comment: hi ryan, Id did not worked.

Comment: Try `fdList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("\"ENT-QA\"*","","")`. The asterisk should help.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your comments, THis worked for me                 fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('sde."ENT-QA"*',"polygon","")